# bind click event from parent page on image within Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have parent page `abc.html` having function as below

```
function displayImageDialog(path){
  //alert(path);
}
```

And HTML code

```
<iframe src="xyz.html"  onLoad="javascript:onloadCall();" name="loadpageframe" id="loadpageframe"></iframe>
```

Now within the IFrame ,multiple `img` tags are available, how to bind click event on that `img`.Currently I am able to assign title to each `img` tag

```
function onloadCall(){
    var $currIFrame = $('#loadpageframe');
    var img = $currIFrame.contents().find("img");
    for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        img[i].title='Click to enlarge';

        //TODO click event code to pass img src attribute to
        // function displayImageDialog(src)

    }  
}
```

I DONT want to modify my page within IFrame at all.So I am searching for solution

Comment: wht exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to display image in dialog on image click

Comment: OKey let me create a demo for you

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21576617/1131841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this working at my end.

```
function onloadCall(){
var $currIFrame = $('#loadpageframe');
var img = $currIFrame.contents().find("img");
for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
    img[i].title='Click to enlarge';
    img[i].onclick = function(){
        alert('hi');
        displayImageDialog($(this).attr('src'));
    };
    //TODO click event code to pass img src attribute to
    // function displayImageDialog(src)

   }  
}

function displayImageDialog(src){
alert(src);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
 var frm = window.frames["loadpageframe"].window;//if iframe is test

  $(frm).find("img").on("click",function() {
      $(this).attr('title','sometext');
   // do something 
  });
});
```

put this code outside of iframe

Comment: where to put this ? if in onloadCall , it is not working